# Discord bot async/await in error handling

Tags: python, async-await

I'm kinda new on Python and I've been trying to understand how async functions work. With that being said, I'm trying to make a Discord bot with a few user inputs so the bot shows a custom embed. That was the easy part because now I'm stuck on the error handling. Once the bot asks for an input, I want it to ask back if that input is not correct or out of range.

```
        while True:
          value = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=150.0)
          try:
            value = int(value.content)
            if value > 0 or value < 10:
              raise ValueError('A very specific bad thing happened.')
            else:
              break
          except:
            ctx.reply("That's not a valid value")
```

I do know my error is on that `await` inside the loop, but I have no clue how to do it. All I'm looking for is that the bot asks again if it's not correct. _I've been doing a lot of research and I found nothing related to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using the `while` loop? What for? If you are using the `discordpy` library then it is simply a `@client.event  async def on_message(message): ...`. Then you can check the message content and do a response back to the client. If you catch an error you can also send its text to the client if that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.reply` is a coroutine, and it should have an `await` before it.
A way for the command to look better would be to send a message after every iteration, to confirm whether your input was incorrect, or it's some other error.

And you also have a logical error in your code, in the `if`. It raises `ValueError` every time the input is either greater than 0, OR it is less than 10. Which is basically every time you enter an integer. And since the except part is run every time there is an error, it's an infinite loop.
I'm assuming you wanted inputs that were not integers to raise the "Not a valid value" error, in case you didn't, you can change `except:` to `except ValueError:` to run only when there is a ValueError.

Here is the code I wrote

```py
while True:
    await ctx.send("Enter a value:")
    value = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=150.0)
    try:
        value = int(value.content)
        if value > 0 and value < 10:
            raise ValueError('A very specific bad thing happened.')
        else:
            break
    except:
        await ctx.reply("That's not a valid value")
```